# If $gcd(a,b)=1$ then $gcd\big(\frac{a^{p}+b^{p}}{a+b},a+b\big)=1$ unless $p|a+b$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $$\gcd\left(\frac{a^{p}+b^{p}}{a+b},a+b\right)=1$$ unless $p|(a+b)$
Where $p$ is any prime.
Use of modular arithmetic is restricted.
Can you prove it just using basic divisiblity and definition of gcd ?

Comment: For $p=2$, the number $\frac {a^p+b^p}{a+b} $ can be not an integer: for example if $a=1$ and $b=2$. Do you mean odd prime only?

Comment: @Fabio i think it is enough to show this for atleast one p which satisfies this.