# Prove that : $\text{gcd}\bigg(a+b, \frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b}\bigg)=1 \ \text{or} \ p$

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

> If $p$ is an odd prime and $a,b$ are relatively prime integers, prove that :
>   $$\text{gcd}\bigg(a+b, \frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b}\bigg)=1 \ \text{or} \ p$$

Since it's obligatory to show the attempts to avoid the closing of the posts, here's mine :

First of all I tried to simplify :

> Factoring gives :
>   $$\frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b}=a^{p-1}-a^{p-2}+a^{p-3}-a^{p-4}+\dots-a+1$$
>   To calculate $\text{gcd}$, we can reduce it, using the fact that $p$ is an odd prime, since it is odd, $p-1$ is even, hence :
>   \begin{align} \frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b}&=a^{p-1}-a^{p-2}+\dots+a^{2x}-a^{2x-1}+\dots-a+1 \\\
> &=(-1)^{p-1}-(-1)^{p-2}+\dots+(-1)^{2x}-a+1 \ (\text{mod} \ a+1) \\\
> &=1+1+1\dots+1 \equiv p(\text{mod} \ a+1) \end{align}
>   Thus by the Euclidean algorithm :
>   $$\text{gcd}\bigg(a+b, \frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b}\bigg)=\text{gcd}(a+1,p)$$

And here where I'm stuck, I thought  that I'm supposed to rearrange it but, unfortunately I got nothing, Any suggestions ? I'll be really thankful !

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3100848/if-gcda-b-1-then-gcd-big-fracapbpab-ab-big-1-unless-pab?noredirect=1&lq=1   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247146/show-that-gcd-left-fracan-bna-b-a-b-right-gcdn-dn-1-a-b

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Use a similar factorization :
$$\frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b}=a^{p-1}-a^{p-2}b+a^{p-3}b^2+\dots -ab^{p-2}+b^{p-1}$$